# Detect closing the "Request for Permission" window (Google Account login)

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-signin

I'm implementing a Google Account login on my website and I've reached the following problem: when the user chooses to login using his/her Google Account, Google's *[Request for Permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcxsz.png)* popup window opens and, if the user closes it, I have no way of detecting this in any way.

Here's the relevant code, using [GoogleAuth.attachClickHandler](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthattachclickhandlerwzxhzdk76containerwzxhzdk77_wzxhzdk78optionswzxhzdk79_wzxhzdk80onsuccesswzxhzdk81_wzxhzdk82onfailurewzxhzdk83) method:

```
gapi.load('auth2', function() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'my-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
    });
    auth2.attachClickHandler(button, {},
        function(googleUser) {
            successHandler(googleUser);
        }, function(error) {
            failureHandler(error);
        });
});
```

If the user presses *Accept*, **successHandler** is called and if the user presses *Cancel*, **failureHanlder** is called. However, if the user simply closes this window, nothing happens and my website keeps waiting for some callback.

Is there any way to detect this, other than adding a timeout?

Answer (score 0):

So, I guess I came up with a (very ugly) solution. Answers are still welcome, if someone knows of a better way.

Basically, I replace the default `window.open` function with my own and monitor if a Google window opens and then periodically check if it closed:

```
Function.prototype.isNative = function() {
    return this.toString().indexOf('[native code]') > -1;
}

function registerGoogleTimeoutCallback() {
    if (window.open.isNative()) {
        var originalOpen = window.open;
        window.open = function(URL, name, specs, replace) {
            var newWindow = originalOpen(URL, name, specs, replace);
            if (URL.indexOf('https://accounts.google.com/') === 0) {
                var interval = setInterval(function() {
                    if (newWindow.closed) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $(window).trigger('googleWindowClosed');
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
            return newWindow;
        }
    } else {
        throw 'window.open already replaced'
    }
}
```

This way, I use `$(window).on('googleWindowClosed', callback)` to register a failure callback and also `$(window).off('googleWindowClosed')` to unregister it, in case of success.